# How to call blocking mediator results to out sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having a problem with call blocking mediator in a WSO2 Esb proxy service.And i'm currently using wso2 4.9.0.
I am going to call multiple WSO2 ESB Sequence mediator using under the call mediator (using filter statement). This will loop by following XML tag format. Based on the results. I need to call out sequence according to this xml tag value.

Here is my In Sequence:

```
 <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint key="CommonEPR"/>
        </call>

        <filter regex="02" source="json-eval($.responsecode) xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <then>
                <log level="full">
                    <property
                        name="CALLCommonAPI" value="MESSAGE"/>
                </log>
                <sequence name="CommonOutSequence">
                    <log/>
                     <out>
                        <sequence key="CommonOutSequence"/>
                        <send/>
                    </out>
                </sequence>
            </then>
        </filter>
```

What i need is send to results to CommonOutSequence, yes i know its not possible in call mediator send to out sequence.can any one tell me possible way to send out Sequence using call mediator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear about your requirement, but if you want to move to the outflow at some point, you can call the `<loopback/>` mediator[1].

**Updated as per the 1st comment:**

Doesn't this work?

```
        <filter regex="02" source="json-eval($.responsecode) xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <then>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="CALLCommonAPI" value="MESSAGE"/>
                </log>
                <sequence key="CommonOutSequence"/>
                <respond/>
            </then>
        </filter>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Loopback+Mediator

Comment: simply what i need is according to the call blocking results if it contain responsecode 02 call the CommonOutSequence and thru the CommonOutSequence  it will send to Xslt transformation like this <xslt key="xslt-account-validation"/>.
if responsecode 00 do the normal process and continue it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: nope still not my bad. when i gave to <loopback/>still not move.

Comment: `<filter regex="02" source="json-eval($.responsecode) xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <then>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="CALLCommonAPI" value="MESSAGE"/>
                </log>
                <sequence key="CommonOutSequence"/>
              <loopback/>
            </then>
        </filter>`
I think this one can make something green to me.its not go to <sequence key="CommonOutSequence"/>`this, but its move to my  initiate out sequence .since,i can give this <sequence key="CommonOutSequence"/> @bee thnx u save my day.